# How store a range from excel into a Range variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I am reading some cells of excel using VBA.

```
Function getData(currentWorksheet as Worksheet, dataStartRow as Integer, _
dataEndRow as Integer, DataStartCol as Integer, dataEndCol as Integer)

    Dim dataTable as Range
    dataTable = currentWorksheet.Range(currentWorksheet.Cells(dataStartRow, _
    dataStartCol), currentWorksheet.Cells(dataEndRow, dataEndCol))

    getData = dataTable

EndFunction
```

It throws an error, object variable or with block variable not set. How take this range in a variable? Please guide me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you use a `Range` object, you cannot simply use the following syntax:

```
Dim myRange as Range
myRange = Range("A1")
```

You must use the `set` keyword to assign Range objects:

```
Function getData(currentWorksheet As Worksheet, dataStartRow As Integer, dataEndRow As Integer, DataStartCol As Integer, dataEndCol As Integer)

    Dim dataTable As Range
    Set dataTable = currentWorksheet.Range(currentWorksheet.Cells(dataStartRow, DataStartCol), currentWorksheet.Cells(dataEndRow, dataEndCol))

    Set getData = dataTable

End Function

Sub main()
    Dim test As Range

    Set test = getData(ActiveSheet, 1, 3, 2, 5)
    test.select

End Sub
```

Note that every time a range is declared I use the `Set` keyword.

---

You can also allow your `getData` function to return a `Range` object instead of a `Variant` although this is unrelated to the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

What is `currentWorksheet`? It works if you use the built-in `ActiveSheet`.

```
dataStartRow=1
dataStartCol=1
dataEndRow=4
dataEndCol=4
Set currentWorksheet=ActiveSheet
dataTable = currentWorksheet.Range(currentWorksheet.Cells(dataStartRow, dataStartCol), currentWorksheet.Cells(dataEndRow, dataEndCol))
```

Comment: the currentWorksheet is passed as an augmenter to a function in which the statement is. It is Sheet2. It is still throwing the same error though i say Set currentWorksheet - ActiveSheet

Comment: @PriyankThakkar Please update your question to show the *complete* context then. Because the code I posted does work (I tested it).

Comment: @Andrew Leach - that code worked without a Set in front of the dataTable assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Define what GetData is. At the moment it is not defined.

```
Function getData(currentWorksheet as Worksheet, dataStartRow as Integer, dataEndRow as Integer, DataStartCol as Integer, dataEndCol as Integer) as variant
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your dim as a variant, and pull the data as you would from an array.  i.e.

```
Dim y As Variant
y = Range("A1:B2")
```

Now your excel range is all 1 variable (array), y

To pull the data, call the array position in the range "A1:B2" or whatever you choose. e.g.:

```
Msgbox y(1, 1)
```

This will return the top left box in the "A1:B2" range.

Answer (score -1):

here is an example that allows for performing code on each line of the desired areas  (pick either from top & bottom of selection, of from selection

```
Sub doROWSb()           'WORKS    for do selected rows     SEE FIX ROWS ABOVE  (small ver)
Dim E7 As String    'note:  workcell E7 shows:  BG381
E7 = RANGE("E7")    'see eg below
Dim r As Long       'NOTE: this example has a paste formula(s) down a column(s).  WILL REDUCE 10 HOUR DAYS OF PASTING COLUMNS, DOWN TO 3 MINUTES?
Dim c As Long
Dim rCell As RANGE
'Dim LastRow As Long
r = ActiveCell.row
c = ActiveCell.Column   'might not matter if your code affects whole line anyways, still leave as is

Dim FirstRow As Long    'not in use, Delete if only want last row, note: this code already allows for selection as start
Dim LastRow As Long


If 1 Then     'if you are unable to delete rows not needed, just change 2 lines from: If 1, to if 0 (to go from selection last row, to all rows down from selection)
With Selection
    'FirstRow = .Rows(1).row                 'not used here, Delete if only want last row
    LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).row        'find last row in selection
End With
application.CutCopyMode = False             'if not doing any paste op below
Else
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row  'find last row used in sheet
End If
application.EnableEvents = True             'EVENTS  need this?
application.ScreenUpdating = False          'offset-cells(row, col)
'RANGE(E7).Select  'TOP ROW SELECT
RANGE("A1") = vbNullString                  'simple macros on-off switch, vb not here:  If RANGE("A1").Value > 0 Then


For Each rCell In RANGE(Cells(r, c), Cells(LastRow, c)) 'new
    rCell.Select    'make 3 macros for each paste macro below
'your code here:

If 1 Then     'to if 0, if want to paste formulas/formats/all down a column
    Selection.EntireRow.Calculate     'calcs all selected rows, even if just selecting 1 cell in each row (might only be doing 1 row aat here, as part of loop)
Else
'dorows() DO ROWS()
'eg's for paste cells down a column, can make 3 separate macros for each: sub alte() altf & altp
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False    'make sub alte ()    add thisworkbook:  application.OnKey "%{e}", "alte"
      'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False     'make sub altf ()    add thisworkbook:  application.OnKey "%{f}", "altf"
      'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False         'amke sub altp ()    add thisworkbook:  application.OnKey "%{p}", "altp"
End If
Next rCell

'application.CutCopyMode = False            'finished - stop copy mode
'RANGE("A2").Select
goBEEPS (2), (0.25)       'beeps secs
application.EnableEvents = True             'EVENTS

'note:  workcell E7 has: SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",$BG$369),"$",""),"","")
'other col eg (shows: BG:BG):  =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",$BG2),"$",""),ROW(),"")&":"& SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",$BG2),"$",""),ROW(),"")
End Sub


'OTHER:
Sub goBEEPSx(b As Long, t As Double)   'beeps secs as:  goBEEPS (2), (0.25)  OR:  goBEEPS(2, 0.25)
  Dim dt  'as double    'worked wo as double
  Dim x
  For b = b To 1 Step -1
    Beep
    x = Timer
  Do
  DoEvents
  dt = Timer - x
  If dt < 0 Then dt = dt + 86400    '86400 no. seconds in a day, in case hit midnight & timer went down to 0
  Loop Until dt >= t
  Next
End Sub
```