# Searching through columns to give a history of an item

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have several columns in my excel sheet like this. My actual sheet is much more complex and I have a macro for static time. This however is about searching for a specified value then listing all of what is searched for...

So you have this:

```
type item#   date
cat   123451  11/3/14 1:00 pm
dog   154321  12/3/14 2:00 pm
fish  999900  10/4/12 4:00 pm
cat   123651  11/7/14 1:00 pm
dog   154621  12/8/14 2:00 pm
fish  992900  10/1/12 3:00 pm
```

I want to create a search function where you type in the ***type*** and it lists all the information for that type.

so as an example:

```
Search: cat
```

The user simply typed in cat and was given

```
 cat   123651  11/7/14 1:00 pm
 cat   123451  11/3/14 1:00 pm
```

Hopefully...this can be done in some way.

Comment: That sounds very similar to [AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoFilter-to-filter-your-data-7d87d63e-ebd0-424b-8106-e2ab61133d92) - what do you need to achieve that AutoFilter can't do?

Comment: If AutoFilter is not an option, you could use a find loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://trumpexcel.com/2015/01/dynamic-excel-filter/

for anyone that is looking to create a literally search bar in their excel sheet without VBA follow this link.

The other comments are also good here, but this completely avoids VBA.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what barrowc said, probably the best way is to use the built in Autofilter. However, if you want to do some sort of customized search box that is always visible, you could use some VBA like (H5 is your search box):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("H5")) Is Nothing Then
      'Executes on cell change
      Dim criteria as Range
      Set criteria = Range("H5")
      'Range below is the total range of all your data to sort
      'Field is the index of your column you want to sort by (Type)
      Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=criteria.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This will change the autofilter to search for the current value of your search cell.

**Note: untested pseudo-code**

Comment: I know you said that was untested pseudocode...but could you provide a link where I could learn how to get it to work? Like a good tutorial site? I am new to VBA and don't know much about it.

for the code you posted all I have is one error with the line: Dim criteria = Range("M18").Value

Thanks so much for your input and help as this looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem! Looks like I made a mistake in declaring the Range variable. Googled 'How to set a range variable excel vba' and came up with this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236316/how-store-a-range-from-excel-into-a-range-variable. Edited my answer with corrected code. As for overall VBA tutorials, I don't have a specific recommendation. Instead, Google for the basics: declaring a range, getting / setting cells, iterating (looping) through cells. After that, most things will flow together. Good luck!